# Extracting names from filename in Bash

Tags: regex

I have a directory filled with thousands of files in the format LastnameFirstnameYYYYMMDD.pdf. The last and first name will always been in title case.

I'd like to extract the last name so I can move these files to a directory structure of {first letter of last name}/lastname/full filename. Example: DoeJohn20190327 would be moved to D/Doe/DoeJohn20190327

Comment: Check out 'sed' and 'awk'

Comment: I'm not sure if the final destination of the file DoeJohn20190327.pdf is like this:  D/Doe/DoeJohn20190327/DoeJohn20190327.pdf or D/Doe/DoeJohn20190327/DoeJohn20190327.pdf ?

Answer (score 5):

Here you have a solution. I tested it an it creates the folders as you explained.

```bsh
for filename in *.pdf
do
  echo "Processing file $filename "
  first_letter="${filename:0:1}"
  mkdir -p $first_letter #if already exists won't print error
  last_name=$(echo $filename | sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1 \2/g'  |awk '{print $1}')
  mkdir -p $first_letter/$last_name
  mv $filename $first_letter/$last_name
done
```

Answer (score 4):

If the lastname is always the shortest trailing string staring with an upper case letter (there are no compound lastnames for example) you could use a shell parameter expansion of the form `${parameter%pattern}` in place of a regex solution.

Ex.

```
for f in [[:upper:]]*[[:upper:]]*; do 
  d="${f:0:1}/${f%[[:upper:]]*}/"
  echo mkdir -p "$d"
  echo mv "$f" "$d"
done
mkdir -p D/Doe/
mv DoeJohn20190327 D/Doe/
```

Remove the `echo`s when you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

See for example [Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)